# Is there a way to trigger CSS transition by hovering an unrelated DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to trigger a CSS transition in which an overlay covers my bootstrap card when hovering over the header specifically.

The issue I seem to be running into is I can get the transition to work when hovering over the entire card but not specifically the header

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 161, 222);
  background: linear-gradient(170deg, rgba(0, 161, 222, 1) 0%, rgba(2, 154, 212, 1) 41%, rgba(1, 199, 240, 1) 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: 1.5s ease;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.overlay-container:hover .overlay{
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="width: 100%">
  <div class="overlay-container">
    <div class="card-title-top">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="overlay-info">##Placeholder Site name##</div>
      </div>

      <h4 class="card-title-text">Placeholder site name</h4>
    </div>

    <img class="card-img-top" src="img/placeholder-park.jpg" alt="Card image" />

    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="address-list">
        <ul>
          <li>Placeholder sitename</li>
          <li>Placeholder street</li>
          <l1>Placeholder town </l1>
          <li>Placeholder postcode</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="card-weather-image">
        <img src="##PLACEHOLDER##" alt="Card image" height="100px" width="100px" />
      </div>

      <div class="card-bottom-text">
        <p class="card-text">Current Temperature ##placeholder##</p>
      </div>

      <div class="card-btn">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Site</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I believe the issue relates to the overlay container, when replacing  `.overlay-container:hover .overlay` with `.card-title-top:hover .overlay` it instead uses the card title div to apply the 100% height property to and then not fill the way I'd like it. Any help would be massively appreciated!

(where possible I'd like to avoid js / jquery but I understand if this is unavoidable)

Comment: Is your header this ```<h4 class="card-title-text">Placeholder site name</h4>```

Comment: The header is the ```.card-title-top``` 
```<div class="card-title-top">
 <div class="overlay">
  <div class="overlay-info">##Placeholder Site name##</div>
 </div>
 <h4 class="card-title-text">Placeholder site name</h4>
 </div>```

Comment: So after replacing the `overlay-container:hover .overlay` with `.card-title-top:hover .overlay` what is the problem in that , everything is working fine as expected.

Comment: I've been so in my own head trying to solve my issue, I could have sworn I tried this I look a little silly now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `+` selector to get the element just after it

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 161, 222);
  background: linear-gradient(170deg, rgba(0, 161, 222, 1) 0%, rgba(2, 154, 212, 1) 41%, rgba(1, 199, 240, 1) 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: 1.5s ease;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: -1; // you have to get this line however your overlay cannot fully extends
}

.card-title-text:hover+.overlay {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="width: 100%">
  <div class="overlay-container">
    <div class="card-title-top">
      <h4 class="card-title-text">Placeholder site name</h4>
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="overlay-info">##Placeholder Site name##</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <img class="card-img-top" src="img/placeholder-park.jpg" alt="Card image" />

    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="address-list">
        <ul>
          <li>Placeholder sitename</li>
          <li>Placeholder street</li>
          <l1>Placeholder town </l1>
          <li>Placeholder postcode</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="card-weather-image">
        <img src="##PLACEHOLDER##" alt="Card image" height="100px" width="100px" />
      </div>

      <div class="card-bottom-text">
        <p class="card-text">Current Temperature ##placeholder##</p>
      </div>

      <div class="card-btn">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Site</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```